# why can't do the swap to the list

Tags: python, swap

Trying to swap all vowels in a string, the original string is below.
I put indices of all vowels and their counterparts to a list of tuples.

```
s =['a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'i', 'g', 'u', 'k', 'o']
e = [(0, 8), (2, 6), (4, 4), (6, 2), (8, 0)]

for el in e:
    old = el[0]
    new = el[1]

    s[old], s[new] = s[new], s[old]#this does not work

print(s)
```

I wanted the s to become:

```
['o', 'd', 'u', 'f', 'i', 'g', 'e', 'k', 'a']
```

swap a and o, e and u.

but the  string did not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over the all list, you swap the first with the last and than the last with the first, so you are back to the starting point. Iterate to the middle of the list:

```
for old, new in e[:len(e) // 2]:
    s[old], s[new] = s[new], s[old]
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything you swapped, you swapped twice... If you swap `0` with `8`, then `8` with `0`, you've put it all back in the original order.

Don't do swaps twice for the same elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the mapping to a reverse-lookup dict, so that you can map the indices of the list accordingly if it's in the mapping:

```
mapping = dict(map(reversed, e))
print([s[mapping.get(i, i)] for i in range(len(s))])
```

This outputs:

```
['o', 'd', 'u', 'f', 'i', 'g', 'e', 'k', 'a']
```